# tiles pure config xml shown up

Tags: spring, tiles

Please understand my English is not good.

I'm in charge of maintaining a website with Spring and tiles for MVC & VIEWs.

Tiles doesn't show me a proper output and there's no java error message printed on console. and instead of right output of tiles, the pure xml file show out...

here're my sources and output that printed on web browser.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-root-applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security-applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-class>DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-child-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Map modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "/home/member/login.htiles";
}
```

---

**tiles-layouts.xml**

```
<definition name="layouts_home_tiles" template="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layouts_home_tiles.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header"    value="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/home_header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="content"   value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer"    value="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/home_footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="*.htiles" extends="layouts_home_tiles">
    <put-attribute name="content"   value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="*/*.htiles" extends="layouts_home_tiles">
    <put-attribute name="content"   value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}/{2}.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="*/*/*.htiles" extends="layouts_home_tiles">
    <put-attribute name="content"   value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}/{2}/{3}.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="*/*/*/*.htiles" extends="layouts_home_tiles">
    <put-attribute name="content"   value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

---

**layouts_sub_tiles.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="t"%>

<t:insertAttribute name="header"/>
<t:insertAttribute name="content"/>
<t:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
```

---

**Web browser Output**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="t"%>

<t:insertAttribute name="header"/>
<t:insertAttribute name="content"/>
<t:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
```

Comment: thank you for good modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified **web.xml**

/* to /

this solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `TilesViewResolver` in your context, apart from resolver used for jsp (usually `InternalResourceViewResolver`).

Here's a config snippet that works for me:

```
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="0" /> <!-- you need to tell spring to use this resolver first, hence order=0 -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions" value="PATH_TO_YOUR_TILES_XML_CONFIG" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="1" /><!-- this resolver will be used if the view can't be resolved by tiles resolver  hence order=1-->

            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @PatrickJeon anything in the logs? set logs for org.springframework.web on debug level if you can

Answer (score 0):

@soulcheck This is the output of DEBUG LEVEL Log, which I don't really understand. Thank you for your concerning

```
 INFO annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider[registerDefaultFilters(186)] : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doFindMatchingFileSystemResources(552)] : Looking for matching resources in directory tree [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\admin] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor_demo] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\mobile] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap\admin] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap\home] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap\monitor] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap\monitor_demo] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap\note] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\sqlmap\project] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[doRetrieveMatchingFiles(614)] : Searching directory [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\project] for files matching pattern [D:/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cyoz/WEB-INF/classes/com/byto/**/*.class]
DEBUG support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver[_findPathMatchingResources(353)] : Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/byto/**/*.class] to resources [file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\admin\AdminController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\admin\AdminService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\admin\AdminServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config\BytoSendmail.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config\Constant.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config\encodeCookie.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config\PageNavigation.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config\StringUtil.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\config\Unescape.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\LoginCheck.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\LoginFailure.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\LoginSuccess.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\LoginUser.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\LogoutCheck.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\RememberMe.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\login\RememberMeAuth.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\MainController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\MainService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\home\MainServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\HomeController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\HomeService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\HomeServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor\MonitorController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor\MonitorService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor\MonitorServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor_demo\MonitorDemoController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor_demo\MonitorDemoService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\monitor_demo\MonitorDemoServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json\ErrorMessage.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json\GetXMLData.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json\JsonController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json\JsonService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json\JsonServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\json\Sync.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\mobile\NoteController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\mobile\NoteService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\openapi\note\mobile\NoteServiceImpl.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\project\ProjectController.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\project\ProjectService.class], file [D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\cyoz\WEB-INF\classes\com\byto\project\ProjectServiceImpl.class]]
DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory[doGetBean(242)] : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[getFilters(195)] : Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/home/'; to: '/home/'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[getFilters(202)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /**; matched=true
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[readSecurityContextFromSession(130)] : No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[loadContext(88)] : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter[doFilter(67)] : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG session.SessionManagementFilter[doFilter(87)] : Requested session IDE5DEEABF96803AAC5BA0A76B61C2769F is invalid.
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(375)] : /home/ at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[lookupAttributes(173)] : Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/home/'; to: '/home/'
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[extractMatchingAttributes(200)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /admin/**; matched=false
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[extractMatchingAttributes(200)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /home/board/**; matched=false
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[extractMatchingAttributes(200)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /project/**; matched=false
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[extractMatchingAttributes(200)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /monitor/; matched=false
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[extractMatchingAttributes(200)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /monitor/reg_app; matched=false
DEBUG expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[extractMatchingAttributes(200)] : Candidate is: '/home/'; pattern is /monitor/reg_app_check; matched=false
DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor[beforeInvocation(182)] : Public object - authentication not attempted
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy[doFilter(362)] : /home/ reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doService(693)] : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/home/]
DEBUG annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping[getHandlerInternal(221)] : Mapping [/home/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [com.byto.openapi.home.MainController@1c869e8f] and 2 interceptors
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doDispatch(769)] : Last-Modified value for [/home/] is: -1
DEBUG support.HandlerMethodInvoker[invokeHandlerMethod(173)] : Invoking request handler method: public java.lang.String com.byto.openapi.home.MainController.main(java.util.Map,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
DEBUG ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate[execute(168)] : Opened SqlMapSession [com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl@5629626a] for iBATIS operation
DEBUG sql.Connection[debug(27)] : {conn-100006} Connection
DEBUG ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate[execute(185)] : Obtained JDBC Connection [Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection  from DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1e0c386d]] for iBATIS operation
DEBUG sql.Connection[debug(27)] : {conn-100006} Preparing Statement:   SELECT wr_id,wr_subject,wr_content,  DATE_FORMAT(wr_idate, '%Y.%m.%d') AS wr_idate,  wr_del_flag,wr_hit,wr_category,wr_notice,wr_file1,wr_file2,wr_file1_count,wr_file2_count  FROM byto_board_notice WHERE wr_del_flag=0  ORDER BY wr_id DESC LIMIT 7   
DEBUG datasource.DataSourceUtils[doGetConnection(110)] : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG sql.PreparedStatement[debug(27)] : {pstm-100007} Executing Statement:   SELECT wr_id,wr_subject,wr_content,  DATE_FORMAT(wr_idate, '%Y.%m.%d') AS wr_idate,  wr_del_flag,wr_hit,wr_category,wr_notice,wr_file1,wr_file2,wr_file1_count,wr_file2_count  FROM byto_board_notice WHERE wr_del_flag=0  ORDER BY wr_id DESC LIMIT 7   
DEBUG sql.PreparedStatement[debug(27)] : {pstm-100007} Parameters: []
DEBUG sql.PreparedStatement[debug(27)] : {pstm-100007} Types: []
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} ResultSet
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Header: [wr_id, wr_subject, wr_content, wr_idate, wr_del_flag, wr_hit, wr_category, wr_notice, wr_file1, wr_file2, wr_file1_count, wr_file2_count]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [9, 공지입니다, 공지입니다, 2011.11.07, 0, 18, 일반공지, 0, , , 0, 0]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [8, 공지입니다, 공지입니다, 2011.11.07, 0, 3, 일반공지, 0, , , 0, 0]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [7, 공지입니다 공지입니다 공지입니다 공지입니다, 공지입니다 , 2011.11.07, 0, 5, 일반공지, 0, , , 0, 0]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [6, 공지입니다 공지입니다, 공지입니다공지입니다공지입니다공지입니다공지입니다 , 2011.11.07, 0, 7, 일반공지, 0, , , 0, 0]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [5, 공지입니다, 공지입니다, 2011.11.07, 0, 3, 일반공지, 0, , , 0, 0]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [4, 공지입니다, 공지입니다, 2011.11.03, 0, 5, 일반공지, 0, login_201111031845341.gif, , 4, 0]
DEBUG sql.ResultSet[debug(27)] : {rset-100008} Result: [3, 공지사항 입니다, 공지사항 입니다, 2011.11.03, 0, 6, 일반공지, 0, , , 0, 0]
DEBUG datasource.DataSourceUtils[doReleaseConnection(332)] : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[render(1045)] : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView: name 'home/index.htiles'; URL [home/index.htiles]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG tiles2.TilesView[exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(328)] : Added model object 'mainNoticeList' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'home/index.htiles'
DEBUG impl.BasicTilesContainer[render(615)] : Render request recieved for definition 'home/index.htiles'
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doService(693)] : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layouts_home_tiles.jsp]
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping[lookupHandler(266)] : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layouts_home_tiles.jsp] are [/**]
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping[lookupHandler(290)] : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layouts_home_tiles.jsp] are {}
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping[getHandlerInternal(221)] : Mapping [/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layouts_home_tiles.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@3789346e] and 2 interceptors
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doDispatch(769)] : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layouts_home_tiles.jsp] is: -1
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doDispatch(824)] : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[processRequest(674)] : Successfully completed request
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[processRequest(674)] : Successfully completed request
DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter[doFilter(100)] : Chain processed normally
DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[saveContext(338)] : SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[doFilter(89)] : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doService(693)] : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping[lookupHandler(266)] : Matching patterns for request [/favicon.ico] are [/**]
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping[lookupHandler(290)] : URI Template variables for request [/favicon.ico] are {}
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping[getHandlerInternal(221)] : Mapping [/favicon.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@3789346e] and 2 interceptors
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doDispatch(769)] : Last-Modified value for [/favicon.ico] is: -1
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[doDispatch(824)] : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet[processRequest(674)] : Successfully completed request
```